# How to call a specific function from inside a subfunction in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

How do I call function "a" from "a.v" without a direct reference "a()"

```
function a(){
    alert("1");
    this.v=function(){alert("hi")};
}
```

Comment: How do you call a function without calling it?

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of doing this without repeating `a`:

```
function a(){
    let indirect = arguments.callee;
    alert("1");
    indirect.v=function(){ indirect(); };
}

a();
a.v();
```

But this does not work under strict mode and you must call `a` before calling `a.v`.

You could also do:

```
function a(){
   alert('1');
   this.v = () => this();
}

a.v = a;
a.v();
```

This way you don't call `a()` and it also works under strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Set its `v` property outside the function:

```js
function a() {
  alert("1");

}

a.v = function() {
  a()
  alert("hi")
};

a.v()
```